# adding models to backbone collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js

I have a rails app with 4 Model classes, with multiple instances in each table.  I have created backbone Model and Collection classes in CoffeeScript to match.  I can successfully load all of the collections and can render them in views.  So far, so good. Here is one of my collections, with its associated model:

```
class window.CoffeeWater.Collections.Histories extends Backbone.Collection
url: '/api/histories'
model: History

class window.CoffeeWater.Models.History extends Backbone.Model
```

I need to be able to create a History model object, and then add it to the Histories collection.  The documentation states that I have to set a 'collection' property when creating my new model, in order for it to get the 'url' property from the collection.  My problem is that I can't seem to set the 'collection' property value correctly, because the url property does not get set on the model instance

```
attributes = {'start_time': new Date (1434740259016), 'stop_time': new Date (1434740259016 +(86400*1000)), 'valve_id': 2}
options = { collection: window.CoffeeWater.Collections.Histories }
history = new window.CoffeeWater.Models.History(attributes, options)
window.CoffeeWater.Objects.Collections.Histories.add(history)
```

Inspecting the resulting 'history' object does not show the same attributes that exist in models already in the collection, and the url property is missing.

I am currently at a loss.  Does anyone have an example on how to do this?  The backbone.js docs do not show any relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

The way the url in model is defined like this.

If there is a url property in model.

```
class window.CoffeeWater.Models.History extends Backbone.Model
url:'/api/history/1'
```

Then when model.fetch(), it will call that url. If this property is not found, it will see if the associated collection does have a 'url'. You try to set this collection variable.

What you are missing is this. This

```
class window.CoffeeWater.Collections.Histories extends Backbone.Collection
```

is actually a definition of a class. It is not an object yet. You need to initialize it, like you do in java. so

```
var historyCollection=new window.CoffeeWater.Collections.Histories()
```

Now you have a collection object. When you do

```
historyCollection.add(history);
```

The "collection" of model is automatically set to the "historyCollection" object, which contains a 'url'. So in fact, you do not need to manually put this in the option.

basically

```
attributes = {'start_time': new Date (1434740259016), 'stop_time': new Date (1434740259016 +(86400*1000)), 'valve_id': 2} 
var historyCollection=new window.CoffeeWater.Collections.Histories()
var history = new window.CoffeeWater.Models.History(attributes)
historyCollection.add(history)
```